# updating onlistitemclick listview from async just really confused

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, listactivity

Ok this is my first every android app so don't bash me. I am very open to suggestion if I am doing anything wrong or weird so please don't be shy. I'm have a little bit of trouble updating my listview after I click on an item. Anyways here's the code... I just don't understand how it works I think...

**[ MainActivity.java ]**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp2;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.text.method.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{
    public CustomAdapter adapterMain;
    private FtpConnectionTask ftpTask;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Vector<RowData> data;
    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        xBins(textView);
    }



    /*public void addItems( ListView parent ) 
     {
     CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
     RowData rd = new RowData("item4", "description4");
     data.add(rd);
     rd = new RowData("item5", "description5");
     data.add(rd);
     rd = new RowData("item6", "description6");
     data.add(rd);

     CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.row, R.id.item, data);
     setListAdapter(adapter);    
     getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
     }*/

    public void onListItemClick( ListView parent, View v, int position, long id )
    {
        ftpTask.row = ftpTask.adapter.getItem(position);        
        String ftpItem = ftpTask.row.mItem;
        if ( ftpTask.row.mDescription == "dir" ) 
        {
            String[] args = new String[] { ftpItem };
            Object[] aObject = new Object[] { "cd", args, this };
            //ftpTask.adapter.clear();
            //ftpTask.processCmd(aObject);
        }
    }

    private class RowData
    {
        protected String mItem;
        protected String mDescription;

        RowData( String item, String description )
        {
            mItem = item;
            mDescription = description;       
        }

        @Override
        public String toString( )
        {
            return mItem + " " + mDescription;
        }
    }

    private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData>
    {

        public CustomAdapter( Context context, int resource,
                             int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects )
        {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

        }

        @Override
        public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
        {
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            //widgets displayed by each item in your list
            TextView item = null;
            TextView description = null;

            //data from your adapter
            RowData rowData= getItem(position);


            //we want to reuse already constructed row views...
            if ( null == convertView )
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            // 
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            item = holder.getItem();
            item.setText(rowData.mItem);

            description = holder.getDescription();     
            description.setText(rowData.mDescription);

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for row data.
     *
     */
    private class ViewHolder
    {   
        private View mRow;
        private TextView description = null;
        private TextView item = null;

        public ViewHolder( View row )
        {
            mRow = row;
        }

        public TextView getDescription( )
        {
            if ( null == description )
            {
                description = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.description);
            }
            return description;
        }

        public TextView getItem( )
        {
            if ( null == item )
            {
                item = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.item);
            }
            return item;
        }    
    }
    public void xBins( View view )
    {
        IrcConnectionTask task = new IrcConnectionTask();
        task.execute(new Object[] { "irc.efnet.pl", 6667, "sgd5", this });
    }
}
```

**[ IrcConnectionTask.java ]**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp2;

import android.os.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class IrcConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String>
{
    MainActivity callerActivity;
    private Socket socket;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        String response = "";
        String host = (String)params[0];
        Integer port = (Integer)(params[1]);
        String nick = (String)params[2];
        callerActivity = (MainActivity)params[3];
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(host, port);
            String msg1 = "NICK " + nick;
            String msg2 = "USER sur 8 * :be";
            String messages[] = { msg1, msg2 };
            InputDumper task = new InputDumper();
            task.execute(new Object[] { socket, messages, nick, callerActivity});
        }
        catch ( UnknownHostException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        //textView.setText(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String result)
    {
        //textView.setText(result);
    }
}
```

**[ InputDumper.java ]**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp2;

import android.os.*;
import android.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class InputDumper extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String>
{
    MainActivity callerActivity;
    private String response = "";
    private Integer i = 0;
    private Boolean Connected = false;
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)params[0];
            String messages[] = (String[])params[1];
            String nickname = (String)params[2];
            callerActivity = (MainActivity) params[3];
            //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("USERNAME: (.*)");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String msg;
            while ((msg = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (msg.indexOf("USERNAME:") > 0) 
                {
                    new FtpConnectionTask().execute(new Object[] { nickname, "emulation", callerActivity });
                    publishProgress("FTP CONNECTION STARTED!!!");
                }
                if (msg.startsWith("PING")) 
                {
                    String PONG = "PONG " + msg.substring(msg.indexOf(":"));
                    new OutputWriter().execute(new Object[] { socket, PONG, callerActivity });
                    Connected = true;
                }
                else if (i == 4)
                {
                    for (String message : messages)
                    {
                        new OutputWriter().execute(new Object[] { socket, message, callerActivity });
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 13) //msg.endsWith("servers"))
                {
                    new OutputWriter().execute(new Object[] { socket, "JOIN #xbins", callerActivity });
                }
                else if (i == 20)
                {
                    new OutputWriter().execute(new Object[] { socket, "PRIVMSG #xbins :!list", callerActivity });
                }
                response += msg;
                publishProgress(msg);
                i++;
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        //textView.setText(result);
    }
    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress)
    {
        textView = (TextView) callerActivity.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        textView.append(Html.fromHtml("<font color='green'>" + progress[0] + "</font><br />"));
        final int scrollAmount = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(textView.getLineCount())
            - textView.getHeight();
        // if there is no need to scroll, scrollAmount will be <=0
        if (scrollAmount > 0)
            textView.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount);
        else
            textView.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}
```

**[ OutputWriter.java ]**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp2;

import android.os.*;
import android.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class OutputWriter extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String>
{
    MainActivity callerActivity;
    private String response = "";
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)params[0];
            String message = (String)params[1];
            callerActivity = (MainActivity)params[2];
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            bufferedWriter.write(message + "\n\r");
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            publishProgress(message);
        } 
        catch (IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        //textView.setText(result);
    }
    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress)
    {
        textView = (TextView) callerActivity.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        textView.append(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>" + progress[0] + "</font><br />"));
        final int scrollAmount = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(textView.getLineCount())
            - textView.getHeight();
        // if there is no need to scroll, scrollAmount will be <=0
        if (scrollAmount > 0)
            textView.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount);
        else
            textView.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}
```

**[ FtpConnectionTask.java ]**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp2;

import android.os.*;
import android.text.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.app.*;

public class FtpConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String>
{
    public static CustomAdapter adapter;
    public static RowData row;
    MainActivity callerActivity;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public Vector<RowData> data;
    private FTPClient mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
    protected String doInBackground( Object... params )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( mFTPClient.isConnected() )
            {
                Log.v("TESTING", "Is connected");
                String cmd = (String)params[0];
                String[] args = (String[])params[1];
                callerActivity = (MainActivity) params[2];
                if (cmd == "cd")
                {
                    mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(args[0].toString());
                    String[] names = mFTPClient.listNames();
                    listRemote(names);
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                String user = (String)params[0];
                String pass = (String)params[1];
                callerActivity = (MainActivity) params[2];
                mFTPClient.connect("distribution.xbins.org");
                mFTPClient.login(user, pass);
                mFTPClient.enterLocalActiveMode();
                mFTPClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                publishProgress("WORKING DIR: " + mFTPClient.printWorkingDirectory());
                publishProgress("LOGGED IN");
                String[] names = mFTPClient.listNames();
                listRemote(names);
                FTPFile[] remoteFiles = mFTPClient.listFiles();
                for ( FTPFile remoteFile : remoteFiles ) //int i = 0; i < remoteFiles.length; i++)
                {
                    if ( remoteFile.getType() == FTPFile.FILE_TYPE ) 
                    {
                        String name = remoteFile.getName();
                        long length = remoteFile.getSize();
                        String readableLength = FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(length);
                        publishProgress(name + ":\t\t" + readableLength);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;
    }

    final void listRemote(final String... params)
    {
        callerActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) callerActivity.getSystemService(callerActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                data = new Vector<RowData>();
                for ( String name : params )
                {
                    row = new RowData(name, "dir");
                    data.add(row);
                }

                adapter = new CustomAdapter(callerActivity, R.layout.row, R.id.item, data);
                callerActivity.setListAdapter(adapter);
                callerActivity.getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate( String... progress )
    {
        textView = (TextView) callerActivity.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        textView.append(Html.fromHtml("<font color='yellow'>" + progress[0] + "</font><br />"));
        final int scrollAmount = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(textView.getLineCount())
            - textView.getHeight();
        // if there is no need to scroll, scrollAmount will be <=0
        if ( scrollAmount > 0 )
            textView.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount);
        else
            textView.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    public class RowData
    {
        protected String mItem;
        protected String mDescription;

        RowData( String item, String description )
        {
            mItem = item;
            mDescription = description;       
        }

        @Override
        public String toString( )
        {
            return mItem + " " + mDescription;
        }
    }

    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData>
    {

        public CustomAdapter( Context context, int resource,
                             int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects )
        {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

        }

        @Override
        public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
        {
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            //widgets displayed by each item in your list
            TextView item = null;
            TextView description = null;

            //data from your adapter
            RowData rowData= getItem(position);


            //we want to reuse already constructed row views...
            if ( null == convertView )
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            // 
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            item = holder.getItem();
            item.setText(rowData.mItem);

            description = holder.getDescription();     
            description.setText(rowData.mDescription);

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper for row data.
     *
     */
    public class ViewHolder
    {   
        private View mRow;
        private TextView description = null;
        private TextView item = null;

        public ViewHolder( View row )
        {
            mRow = row;
        }

        public TextView getDescription( )
        {
            if ( null == description )
            {
                description = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.description);
            }
            return description;
        }

        public TextView getItem( )
        {
            if ( null == item )
            {
                item = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.item);
            }
            return item;
        }    
    }
}
```

**[ row.xml]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#00000000">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/item" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/description" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**[ main.xml ]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:id="@+id/txtView"
    android:maxLines = "5"
    android:scrollbars = "vertical" />

    <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you get any exceptions you should post the stacktrace with the exception from the `logcat`. Also I don't understand what is the problem your facing(try to limit the code you post, as it could get really hard to follow if you add to many lines.).

Comment: Are you able to display the `ListView`? If yes, then now what do you want to achieve, Do you want to update your `ListView` on Item Click? What happens on item click? Exception, Activity not responding!!

Comment: Yes my listview shows and I'm trying to update it via onlistitemclick from my MainActivity but the dat I need is from my class FTPConnection asynctask. And I'm just not quite sure how todoit.